# How to find files/folders that change in joomla when content get added from the backend of the site

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I need to know which all files or folders can change in joomla  when an administrator adds content from backend of the site.If possible list those folders/files

Comment: I think you should read up a little about Joomla. No CMS stores content in files as it less secure and would be a major hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla! uses a database to store all content.

Apart from media files, log files, tmp files and maybe cache, Joomla! does not store anything else in files / folders.

Maybe you can expose your problem more clearly. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I need to modify a site which i did 3 months back.Lot of content has been added by the administrator within these months.I plan to download only the new and modified files,import the database, and work on local server.So relevant change occurs only in "media" folder.right? @ Valentin Despa

Comment: Just work with the current version. If you need to see which files changed, get both versions of the website (yours and the current) and compare them with a tool like [WinMerge] http://www.winmerge.org/